# cx_freeze windows console encoding bug

Tags: encoding, cx-freeze, python-3.4

I have python 3.4 script which has deal with  unicode characters, diacritics and etc.
The script works perfectly on Mac and Windows.
If I freeze it to windows executable (freezing on windows!)

```
python cxfreeze verifier.py -cOO --target-dir verifier
```

and will try to run it, it will give me the following exception while performing output

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\cx_Freeze\initscripts\Console.py", line 27, in <module>
exec(code, m.__dict__)
  File "C:\Users\me\Desktop\verifier\verifier.py", line 520, in <module>
main()
  File "C:\Users\me\Desktop\verifier\verifier.py", line 484, in main
ConsoleManager.dynamic_print(MSG_VERIFYING_FILE.format(relativePath))
  File "C:\Users\me\Desktop\verifier\verifier.py", line 230, in dynamic_print
ConsoleManager.print(message, end='\r')
  File "C:\Users\me\Desktop\verifier\verifier.py", line 226, in print
print(message, end=end)
  File "X:\Python34-x32\lib\encodings\cp866.py", line 19, in encode
UnicodeEncodeError: 'charmap' codec can't encode character '\u0456' in position 16: character maps to <undefined>
```

I wonder why 'cp866'? The script is working with utf-8 exclusively and there were no cp866 charset references at all!
Looks like cx_Freeze is trying to print utf-8 stream to console like cp866 stream.

How can i tell to cx_Freeze exe-creator script to perform all console output in utf-8?

I will be glad to any help.

**UPDATE**: found http://sourceforge.net/p/cx-freeze/mailman/message/24126644/ maybe it is about encountered problem

Comment: If Python decides that your console encoding is cp866, it will try to use that when you print unicode strings. I think there is some work to make Python use the unicode API for the Windows console, but it hasn't landed yet. In the meantime, you could write bytes directly to `sys.stdout.buffer` - assuming you know what the correct encoding is.

Comment: When trying the script, did you run it in command line or in some IDE console, like PyDev, IDLE etc.? Because these are usually utf-8, contrary the Windows console.

Comment: @Fenikso, i tried that, cygwin console supports unicode (and Windows' PowerShell supports it too, i guess), and all will going fine if you launch script as is, with python.exe. The problem happened only with freezed script.

Comment: @ThomasK, maybe i will try your solution if i can not workaround cx_freeze bug.

Comment: @ThomasK, i have tried your workaround - it didn't help, because `sys.stdout.buffer.write(message.encode('utf-8'))` writes utf-8 stream, but output encoding is still cp866, as far as i understand and we see weird cp866 symbols at output

Comment: If your console is using cp866, then those are the only characters you can print using the standard Python APIs. Have a look at [win_unicode_console](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/win_unicode_console), which might help you. It sounds like this might get fixed for Python 3.5.

Comment: Thank you @ThomasK! win_unicode_console really helped me workaround this problem with console. By the way there were plenty of errors, some of them are described here http://comments.gmane.org/gmane.comp.python.cx-freeze.user/1856 , such as AttributeError when freezing script

Answer (score 0):

Try to execute the following in your windows console:

```
chcp 65001
set PYTHONIOENCODING=utf-8
```